# async waterfall push coding

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am new to Node.JS programming. Any thoughts of my following problem, would be of great help.

I have the following async.waterfall code with sequence of three WasterfallTasks
calling dependent REST API calls in these three tasks.

```
router.get('/:inputId', function(req, res, next) {
var inputId = req.params.inputId;
var waterfallTasks = [];
waterfallTasks.push(function(callback) {
    request(req, "/admin/id/" + inputId, function(error, results) {
        var result = {};
        result.grpInfo = results;
    //result.params = results.params;
        callback(error, result);
    });
});
waterfallTasks.push(function(result1, callback) 
var userID = result1.grpInfo.x.userID[1];
        request(req, userID, "/con/metrix/", function(error,results){
       result1.error=error;
       result1.metrix=results;
       callback(null,result1);
waterfallTasks.push(function(result2,callback)
       request(req, "/xx/xy/", function(error, results){
       callback(error,result3);
     }); }); 
async.waterfall(waterfallTasks, function(error, results){
     if(!error) {
        res.render('TestDetails',{
            'properties' : results.properties,
         // 'params': "result.params,
              'error': results.error }); });
```

My questions are:

- Can I bring any parameters from the first waterfallTask function
  call to the final async.waterfall call for rendering(like the way I
  commented with //). Is it possible?
- If I have to additional properties(JSON as well) from a different API
  and add to this async function, what is the best way to do it? like
  can I call that API in the "result2" function and pass it?

Thank you

Comment: Please format you code. You are missing  curly brackets and it looks like you third task is being added from within your second one, which is probably not want you are doing.

Comment: @Jim, If i understand your question correctly, you already answered the first part yourselves. result.params = results.params would be the easiest way to pass it to second function. you can access them in result1.params. as for Part ii of your question, you can do anything inside waterfall function.as long as you do callback after you are done. Also Please format your code. It is very difficult to follow your code.

Comment: Yeah, please format this, and then I will come look at ti.

Comment: I could able to fix this using async.mapSeries while placing the callback in the end. Thanks for your comments and help.